# Does anyone else have to close MATLAB before Gitlab pulls from a Master Branch?

Tags: git, matlab

I can't post the screen capture from Gitlab Bash due to sensitive information issues, but I had several permission errors and a patch failed message while trying to pull changes from a Master Branch.  After closing MATLAB the heinous evil disappeared. Anyone find a way to work around something like this without closing MATLAB?

Comment: If you are working on a file versioned file, and you try to do a pull to you repo and that same file haves some changes, but it's locked by matlab, then it's obvious that you need to close matlab in order to pull the files :)

Comment: I use Github. MATLAB sucks when I pull. I can commit, add, refresh, push. But I do manually pull with Git Bash, because MATLAB randomly crashes (not always though)

Comment: @Hackerman MATLAB has git support, so technically, if you pull from MATLAB, then conflicts arise and you can fix them

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, yeah *technically*...but maybe this issue get fixes on a new version of MatLab

Comment: Is it only code in your repository or are there other files that you are opening? On Windows, at least, MATLAB does not lock `*.m` files.

Answer (score 0):

My workflow is pretty simple I have a development branch and when others merge to the Gitlab Master; I pull those changes into my development. I'm totally new to Gitlab, so its likely I'm going something silly.  I'm on Windows and use GitBash to pull, push etc.. without closing Matlab, I seem to often get conflicts in my files; when closing Matlab those conflicts don't happen. Its not elegant, but closing Matlab then pulling seems to be the fix.  Thanks for your comments and suggestion.